# How to perform splitting?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

```
Apart[(n + 2)/(n (n + 1) 2^n), n]
```

get the result:

```
2^(1 - n)/n - 2^-n/(1 + n)
```

How to split the term to this form?

```
2 (1/(n 2^n) - 1/((n + 1) 2^(n + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2 (Apart[(n + 2)/(n (n + 1) 2^n), n]/2 // Expand)`